# Accessing HashMap action variables using JSONObject in JSP file

Tags: json, jsp, struts2, struts, hashmap

I am working with **Struts2** with  java action class and view **JSP** file.

My Action class has a variable named:

```
HashMap<Integer, Boolean>  pcksHavingFet;
List<pck> pcks;
int fet;
```

*In pcks, I am having a list of pck's with primary key pckId.
I am having a code function in action class that evaluates pcks and assign true/false based on if pck is/is not associated with fet in Database. So we get a fully evaluated expression for pcksHavingFet Map.*

```
//Code that evaluates and set pcksHavingFet varaible. 
//Create A JSON Object to access this Map variable in JSP.
public void function()
{
// code to populate pcksHavingFet with key/value pair.
//e.g, pcksHavingFet  = {1:true, 2:fALSE, 6:TRUE, 17:false, 11:true .....}

//Create JSON Object to access Map in JSP file
JSONObject jasonfeat = new JSONObject();
jasonfeat.accumulateAll(pcksHavingFet  );
}
```

In Jsp File,

I need to access this pcksHavingFet Map Variable.

I am using below function to show/hide fetDropdown drop down based on pckId is true/false calculated from Map pcksHavingFet.

```
function pcksOnChange(pckId)
{ 
var pcksHavingFet = <ww:property value="pcksHavingFet "/> ;
<ww:set name="pcksHavingFet" value="%{JSONObject.fromObject(pcksHavingFet)}">
</ww:set>
fetDropdown.style.display = (pcksHavingFet [pckId]) ? "" : "none";
}
```

But I am able to see populated values in my action class for pcksHavingFet  variables. But In JSP file, unable to access it though. Its coming as empty Map.

Please help me in accessing successfully this variable. It will be a gr8 help. I am new to JSON, Please elaborate your suggestion/help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are not using Struts2 Build in mechanism to handle JSON.Struts2 provide [Json-plugin].[1](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/json-plugin.html)

The JSON plugin is bundled with Struts since 2.1.7+

All you need to do is to add the plugin jar jar in your class path and need to extends `json-default` in place of struts-default and you are good to go.

Suggest you to read plugin page for details and example how to work with JSON inside Struts2

1. [Strus2-Json](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/json-plugin.html)

just as a side note `ww` represent web-work which has now merged in to Struts2 so its a bit more clear to use tag- alias as `s` in-place of `ww`, but the end choice is all yours.

When you are asking question about Struts2 better tag them with struts2 not struts :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually I am managing a software and need to go with the current implementation. Please if you could provide any help for the above scenario and tell me my fault in jsp/action to access the json Map variable, it would be gr8 help. Though I am looking into JSON plugins.   :-)

Comment: Quick question do you have getter ans setters for your map in your action class?? or make the properties as public bt that's not a good idea